# Sort WP Search results by date

Tags: search

I know we can easily sort WP search results by appending **&orderby=post_date&order=desc** to the search URL like this:

`https://www.example.com/s=search+terms&orderby=post_date&order=desc`

How do I implement this natively to search form code I am using:

`<form method="get" action="https://www.example.com/" id="sv2"><input name="s" id="s" size="30" title="Search example.com" type="search" placeholder="Search example.com"></form>`

Pls help!

Perhaps a code for functions.php is required.

Comment: The same way the search parameter is set. You just need an `<input>` (or `<select>`) with `name="orderby"` or `name="order"` and a value or options set to the parameter values you need. If the parameters aren't selectable by the user then  just use a `hidden` input. Note that this is all HTML form behaviour, and nothing to do with WordPress.

Comment: Although sam221088's answer works fine but for my custom them, this worked more easily. Thanks a lot, it saved my time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@KA.MVP You can create hidden fields for 'orderby' and 'order' with default values 'post_date' and 'desc' or 'asc' in it, you can also put this form inside add_shortcode function explained below and use wherever you want to use by adding shortcode [custom_search_form]

```
function search_form_func()
{
    ?>
    <form method="get" action="https://www.example.com/" id="sv2">
        <input name="s" id="s" size="30" title="Search example.com" type="search" placeholder="Search example.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="post_date">
        <input type="hidden" name="order" value="desc">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    <?php
}
add_shortcode('custom_search_form','search_form_func');
```

Comment: Seems exactly what I was looking for. I know I can add this to functions.php but how do I call it on WP template like index.php?

Comment: you can use do_shortcode function to implement shortcode function in your template
<?php echo do_shortcode('[custom_search_form]'); ?>

Comment: I confirm, this works completely fine! Thanks!!

Comment: There’s no reason to call do_shortcode in a template. You can just use the code directly.